# C for loop with two conditions

Tags: c, for-loop

Is it possible to use a for loop with 2 conditions? I cannot find anything similar in the internet.
If yes can someone tell me the syntax? Or if no does anyone have any Idea how i could do it else?
Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i<4; i++ && int a = 4;a>0;a--){

    mess.stc[i] = ((mess.Acal[a][0] - mess.Uref) - (mess.Acal[a-1][0] - mess.Uref))
            / (kali.ApH[a] - kali.ApH[a-1]);
    mess.tcal[i] = (mess.Acal[a][1] + 273.1 + mess.Acal[a-1][1] + 273.1) / 2;
    mess.Stcal[i] = (double) mess.stc[i] / mess.tcal[i];

}
```

I saw a post, which said its possible with && but i receive the error:

```
../AD7793/Messung.c:604:29: error: expected expression before 'int'
  604 | for (int i = 0; i<4; i++ && int a = 4;a>0;a--){
      |                             ^~~
../AD7793/Messung.c:606:28: error: 'a' undeclared (first use in this function)
  606 |  mess.stc[i] = ((mess.Acal[a][0] - mess.Uref) - (mess.Acal[a-1][0] - mess.Uref))
```

Comment: It needs to be declared in the first statement like `for (int i = 0, a = 0; i < 4 && a < 4 && a > 0; a--)` Your logic would be the equivalent to initializing `a` to 4 on every iteration which isn't desired

Comment: @git-bruh `a < 4` considering the definition of `a` and `a--`,  makes no sense at all

Comment: Oh sorry i added in by mistake as the `i < 4` condition was there aswell, didn't notice it

Answer (score 2):

You cant add variable definitions wherever you want in the for loop statement.

You probably want:

```
    for (int i = 0, a = 4; i < 4 && a > 0; i++ ,a--){
```

Comment: Just a note for OP: declaring both `i` and `a` in the first statement of the `for` loop works because they both have the same type (`int` in this case). This won't work if you want to declare two variables of different type (e.g.: `for (int x = 0, long y = 0; ...; ...)` won't work).

Comment: And in case it isn't obvious to OP, the variables can be declared before the `for` loop, but their scope will then extend beyond the `for` loop to the end of the enclosing block.